# What to do if queryset is none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a News model, where each instance has a unique date. Which means that every day has exactly one News-instance related to it. I am redirecting to the detail-view of the News-instance from the navbar.

To achieve this am I using a context_processor. The context_processor.py file looks like this:

```
from news.models import TodayNews
import datetime


def todays_news(request):
    todays_news = TodayNews.objects.get(date=datetime.date.today())
    return {'news': todays_news}
```

This works completely fine as long as the News model has an instance on that particular date. Otherwise it returns the following error (which is very logical):

```
TodayNews matching query does not exist.
```

My question is, how can I do something different if the query is empty, for example if one particular date does not have a news-instance? What should I return instead of `'news': todays_news`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a `try`-`except` to return `None` in case the `TodayNews` object is not found:

```
from news.models import TodayNews
import datetime

def todays_news(request):
    try:
        todays_news = TodayNews.objects.get(date=datetime.date.today())
    except TodayNews.DoesNotExist:
        todays_news = None
    return {'news': todays_news}
```

You can also use [**`.first()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) to return the first item, this will return `None` if no item can be found:

```
from news.models import TodayNews
import datetime

def todays_news(request):
    todays_news = TodayNews.objects.filter(date=datetime.date.today()).first()
    return {'news': todays_news}
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these work. The first return the following error 'local variable 'todays_news' referenced before assignment.'.  And the second method returns the same error I experienced myself, which was that the query set is none.

Comment: @RandomMadi: for the first you likely have a typo in the assignment in the `except` clause. For the latter, you probably did not turn `.get(..)` into `.filter(..)`.

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Now they worked, thank you very much. However, which one do you recommend using? My instinct says the second because its shorter...

Comment: I'd say `.first()` in contexts like this. Not so much because it's shorter but because you want `None` as a possible answer.

Comment: You might also prefer a previous news if there's nothing today. `TodayNews.objects.order_by('-date').first()` Defensive coding suggests add `.filter(date__lte=datetime.date.today())` just in case of news from the future by some sort of error.